# Is Polycontrast Interference Photography (PIP) legit?

Tags: radiation

Polycontrast Interference Photography supposedly creates images of a body's "organizing template of energy" by detecting interference patterns in 'ordinary' photographs using special software filters. [[Source](http://www.item-bioenergy.com/pip/index.html)][[Source2](http://www.bi-aura.com/about/index.php?article_id=138#Q1)][[Source3](http://huenergytechscience.blogspot.in/2008/10/electro-scanning-polycontrast.html)]

It has been used to prove that other devices work:

- This article [talks](http://www.vedicradiationsolutions.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=82%3aabout-us&catid=37%3avedicrad&Itemid=218) about using PIP and a "Universal Scanner" to prove that an  anti-radiation chip works:

> Cell phone emits Microwave radiations and their affect of thermal expansions had all ready proved by many web sites. The popcorn test is amazing. These can be arrested by our ANTI RAD CHIP which can be affixed at the back of the cell phones, The convincing results are only be produced either by PIP photography or Universal Scanner.

Other sites also seem to sell stuff using PIP images as "proof", e.g. [Banyan Retreat](http://www.banyanretreat.com/pip.html).

Has there been any evidence that PIP actually works, and that it photographs energy fields not visible through conventional methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there such a thing as an aura?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-aura)

Comment: btw. attaching "anti-rad" crap to phone makes it have worse reception, which in turn makes it boost the signal strength.

Comment: I find it significant the the section of linked web site called "research" is actually blank. And i'm down voting as the claims are so garbled they are not worth trying to address.

Comment: @vartec, that question seems to talk about humans being able to see auras while this one is about some device that they say can see changes in radiation or something like that.
This whole PIP thing feels like a scam and I am looking for a credible argument (dis)proving that the PIP actually shows anything....

Comment: @matt_black, I just did a Web Search and it looks like a few other sites are trying to sell stuff based on a similar "proof".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [blog](http://apothdrawer.blogspot.in/2005/01/pseudocolour-gives-you-pip.html), PIP strongly resembles [false-color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_color) images:

> None of the sites promoting PIP offer peer-reviewed studies, show any
>   consideration of the possibility of such artifacts, or show evidence
>   of consistency of multiple scans taken with the client (after stepping
>   briefly away and back to the apparatus) in the same condition.
>   Whatever is different in the 'after' scan is invariably interpreted as
>   an improvement.
>
> The simplest hypothesis: **PIP is wishful interpretation of the brightness levels in a picture due to ordinary optics**. I think its
>   appeal, like that of the Kirlian photography that preceded it, lies in
>   its gloss of objective science and its ability to produce an
>   attractive image that matches believers' expectations of what an aura
>   or energy field might look like.

From [another](http://skepdic.com/comments/ttcom.html) [article](http://jonn.co.uk/badhomeopathy/modules/news/article.php?storyid=46) debunking PIP:

> As usual with this type of pseudo-science, the proponents
>   unquestioningly accept the traditional physics, chemistry and medicine
>   that suits them, and reject the bits that don't.
>
> I examined the photographs of Chakras ... and I noticed that the walls
>   of the room and the chair seem to have their own energy fields, very
>   similar to those of humans. This raises some questions:
>
> o Does that mean that these inanimate objects are alive?
>
> o Was the red congestion of the patient in picture one transferred to the back of the chair in picture three?
>
> o Does the chair feel congested?
>
> o Should we form a Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Chairs?
>
> If I didn't know better I'd think they were measuring minute
>   differences in temperature.

PIP only gives you a psychedelic false-color image from an ordinary photograph which is unlikely to show anything in the microwave range where cell-phones [operate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_radiation_and_health), so it would be unwise to rely on PIP as proof of the radiation-reducing properties of their chip.

Even if it did work, it would probably make things worse as [@vartec commented](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7667/is-polycontrast-interference-photography-pip-legit#comment30414_7667).